# Need a fast way to write large blocks of data to file in C

Tags: c, file

I am not at all good when it comes to writing large chunks of data to file. I have a simulation which has structs like so

```
typedef struct
{
   int age;
   float height;
   float weight;
   int friends [ 250000 ];
} Person;
```

And I can have as many as 250,000 persons, each with 250000 friends (a clique). Obviously this is a great deal of data. If I want to save each struct so I can later load them, what is the most efficient way in C? Here is what I have considered so far

1. I don't want to create a HUGE string with 250,000 groups of data and then do a single `write` as this will use a great deal of memory
2. I also don't want to create 250,000 different files as doing so may be slow.
3. Appending the files based on index (ie person 1, then person 2...), but this might be slow too.
4. Saving the data as binary (is this more efficient?)

---

**EDIT** I am looking for efficient approaches to using `fwrite ()`, namely whether it's faster to collect all the data and write to a single file, or whether to create multiple files and avoid the overhead of collecting all the data before hand.

Comment: @cnicutar I will edit the question to indicate that I am looking more for an efficient way to use fwrite

Comment: Why not use a database of some sort?

Comment: @mcl I have never actually used a DB before, but I suppose I should look into it

Comment: On a unix system, you might consider the writev(2) system call which performs scatter/gather type IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the people and just store the age, height and weight members (3 fwrites), then a friend_count and then loop over the friends and write them one by one. All of this with fwrite. You don't need to care about optimizing I/O, as the C library will buffer for you and do a big "write" when needed.

Comment: So if I loop over all persons, and did these `fwrite` calls, the C library would not write them immediately, but buffer them for later? That doesn't sound like C.

Comment: Believe me, it's true.. =) That's one of the main differences among using the f-functions from the low level ones (fwrite vs write). You can even set the buffer size with setvbuf if you like. If you are using Linux I recommend using "strace" on the executable to see what's doing, you'll see a big write (not many small writes).

Comment: it would. See the setvbuf(3) function. The fwrites, however, would not be as optimized as they might be, and you would still have the overhead of the fwrite calls themselves. "As few fwrites as possible, as close in size to a multiple of MTU or FS block as possible" is my personal rule of thumb; YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to [partially] reinvent a RDBMS (database).  Reinventing is usually a bad idea.  Consider storing your data in a free database system (e.g. Postgres).  It will have other benefits -- you'll be able to interrogate your data w/o writing C code.
If a database sounds like an overkill, use a simpler, file based database storage library such as BerkleyDB or SQLite.

Comment: would this solve my problem of having huge chunks of data? Could I for example pass it an array of `Persons[100000000000]` and let it deal with it?

Comment: If this were Python, I would just do `marshal.dump ( persons )` where `persons` is the list of all the Person Objects (structs)

Comment: @puk you would add records tying one person to another in a relation called "friendof".  So you would have one table called "person" and one table called "friendof" and for each pair of friends there would be an entry in that table.  This would mean that you don't have to worry about knowing how many friends does a person actually have, it will manage allocating enough space for you.  And you will be able to write SQL queries to ask, say, for a list of friends of friends.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about your structure.

You have a Person structure array, and friends[] contain indexes of other Persons array?

The best way would be to distinguish between a Person and his friends.

This way you have a Person of fixed size, and can store all Persons in a single file, and quickly read back data of Person 12345 - it's at filepos 12345*sizeof(Person) from the beginning of the file.

Friends array can be kept in memory through a

```
int *Friends[MAXFRIENDS]
```

array -- you need MAXFRIENDS*sizeof(int *) more bytes of memory, for 250.000 friends it should be 2 megabytes on a 64-bit system. Small change. Each pointer holds the friend[] array for that person.

Then the friends of a Person are into a file in a directory, called, say, /dd/cc/aabbccdd, where aabbccdd is obtained by sprintf("%08x", PersonIndex). Using dd/cc leads to a slightly more balanced tree. To write the friends file, just point to Friends[PersonIndex] and write as many friend indexes as needed (I'd store FriendsNumber in the Person struct).

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at a library like [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) so you can not only read the file back on this machine, but give the file to someone else and have the platform portability problem taken care of for you.